# Why does this Node app hangs when saving to MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

These codes work perfectly locally and there is data saved to MongoDB and I could pull data from it. However when it is deployed to Heroku, the app hangs at the '.save()' portion. Needless, nothing is saved to MongoDB.

Am I doing anything wrong? Could it be the .env portion?
(Works on repl.it and glitch too but not locally from Visual Studio Code)

Full codes at [github](https://github.com/Paddlepop25/linda-api-microservices-app/blob/master/server.js) if anyone wants to take a peek

urlshortener.html

```
    <form action="api/shorturl/new" method="POST">
      <label for="url_input">URL to be shortened</label>
      <input id="url_input" type="text" name="url" value="https://www.freecodecamp.org">
      <input type="submit" value="POST URL">
    </form>
```

package.json

```
    "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "ejs": "^2.5.6",
        "express": "^4.15.2",
        "heroku": "^7.43.2",
        "mongodb": "^3.6.2",
        "mongoose": "^5.10.7",
        "shortid": "^2.2.15"
```

server.js

```
// init project
require('dotenv').config();
var express = require('express');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var shortid = require('shortid');
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

let uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
mongoose.connect(uri, { 
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true 
});

var cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors({ optionsSuccessStatus: 200 }));  // some legacy browsers choke on 204

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static('public'));

// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html');
});

app.get("/urlshortener", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/urlshortener.html');
});

// testing API endpoint... 
app.get("/api/hello", function (req, res) {
  res.json({ greeting: 'hello API' });
});

// URL Shortener Microservice
// define the schema and build a model to store saved urls
let ShortUrl = mongoose.model('HerokuUrl', new mongoose.Schema({
  original_url:  String,
  short_url:  String,
  suffix:  String
}));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post("/api/shorturl/new", (req, res) => {
  let client_requested_url = req.body.url; // from input box
  let suffix = shortid.generate(); // automatically generated

  // this works
  // res.json({
  //   1: client_requested_url,
  //   2: suffix
  // })

  let newUrl = new ShortUrl({
    original_url: client_requested_url,
    // short_url: client_requested_url + "/api/shorturl/" + suffix,
    short_url: __dirname + "/api/shorturl/" + suffix,
    suffix: suffix // suffix: suffix
  })

  // this works
  // res.json({
  //   'info': newUrl
  // })

  // APP HANGS at this save
  newUrl.save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) return console.error(err);
    res.json({
      original_url: newUrl.original_url,
      short_url: newUrl.short_url,
      suffix: newUrl.suffix // suffix: suffix
    });
  });
});

app.get("/api/shorturl/:suffix", (req, res) => {
  let urlSuffix = req.params.suffix;
  ShortUrl.findOne({ suffix: urlSuffix }).then(foundUrl => {
    res.redirect(foundUrl.original_url);
  });
})

// listen for requests
var listener = app.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Your app is listening on port ' + listener.address().port);
});
```

Comment: Is there some error logge in the console on the server on hitting the `/api/shorturl/new` api?

Comment: Yes, "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)"

Comment: If `newUrl.save()` runs into an error, your request handler with log the `err`, but since you're returning in that case without calling `res.send`, the API will hang, everytime any error is encountered. You can respond with an error without "returning" `console.error(err)` (which stops the execution of the handler), and then figure out what err you're getting and why.

Comment: I changed my code to this and got the error in console: 

"POST https://fcc-api-microservices-app.herokuapp.com/api/shorturl/new 503 (Service Unavailable)"

`newUrl.save((err, doc) => {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    res.send('Does this work?')
  });`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working...
The app hangs at .save() so it has something got to do with the database.
It works locally but not when I push to heroku, so it has something got to do with the environment variable.

I typed `heroku logs --tail` and logged the environment variable which got `undefined` and this:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

So I snooped around Stackoverflow and added the database uri as a config variable in Heroku.
It worked!!!!

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score -1):

Try using mongo db atlas for network storage